# Custom iOS Tab Bar Selected Color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there any way to change the color of the background for when you change the selected tab.

I have everything else sorted but i cant think how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Even if there is a way to do it, apple might reject your application because they are very particular about UI issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this.

> https://github.com/judges/RXCustomTabBar

I have used and its so easy to integrate

You can also try this although i have not tried:

> https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController

Answer (score 0):

99% certain there's no way to do it.  There are numerous re-implementations on http://cocoacontrols.com/ that might be helpful to you.